# How to make pagedjs cross reference work in vitepress?

Tags: vitepress, pagedjs

I referenced the pagedjs doc: https://pagedjs.org/documentation/-cross-references/, it says that cross reference can be made by css's `target-text`. However when I tried it in vitepress, it doesn't work.

The css has already applied to the link, however, the text wasn't show up.

Reproduce: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vite-6c5kno?file=docs%2Fcross-ref.md

[image]

[image]

The `target-text` part was replaced by `var(--pagedjs-088b62c0-38d2-499f-bf12-e82792a64fd8)`.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding a `#`. I was misled by this part:

[image]